# Solving a parabolic PDE numerically with the spectral method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

As a homework question, I am asked to numerically solve the PDE on $x \in [-3, 3]$ and $t \in [0, 0.5]$ with [the spectral method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_method).

$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = (12x^2-4) p + \left[4x(x^2-1)+0.1\right] \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{\beta} \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} \\
$$

with the initial condition $p(x,0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})$ and zero boundary condition $p(-3,t)=p(3,t)=0$.

**Attempt:** By the Chebyshev expansion of the first kind $p(x, t) = \sum_{n=0}^N \tau_n(t) T_n(x)$,

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} =& (12x^2-4) p + \left[4x(x^2-1)+0.1\right] \frac{\partial p}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{\beta} \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} \\
\sum_{n=0}^N \tau_n'(t) T_n(x) =& (12x^2-4) \sum_{n=0}^N \tau_n(t) T_n(x) + \left[4x(x^2-1)+0.1\right] \sum_{n=0}^N \tau_n(t) T_n'(x) - \frac{1}{\beta} \sum_{n=0}^N \tau_n(t) T_n''(x) \\
=& \left(2T_0(x) + 6T_2(x)\right) \sum_{n=0}^N \tau_n(t) T_n(x) + \left(0.1T_0(x) - T_1(x) + T_3(x)\right) \sum_{n=0}^N \tau_n(t) T_n'(x) - \frac{1}{\beta} \sum_{n=0}^N \tau_n(t) T_n''(x) \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Ideally, this would yield one ODE for each $\tau_n(t)$ by the uniqueness of Chebyshev expansion, but the polynomials $12x^2-4$ and $4x(x^2-1)+0.1$ mess everything up.

Since I need a numerical result, I don't think I am supposed to perform the multiplication of Chebyshev polynomials by hand. What should I do next?

Comment: You only need to perform the expansion in the spatial dimension! Then step through time in increments from $0$ to $0.5$. I think Chebyshev polynomials would indeed be best for this because your spatial domain is not really periodic (though I guess you could pretend it was). And I'm pretty sure you should be able to match any (Dirichlet) boundary conditions...

Comment: @Ali OK, I am planning to match the zero boundary conditions with Tau's method, but another problem arises from the PDE itself. Please see the updated post for more details.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing here. You just need to approximate $\partial p/\partial t$ by $\left(p(t)-p(t-\Delta t)\right)/\Delta t$ and step through time in fixed increments. No ODEs required.

Comment: @Ali Could you include more details? My understanding is that approximating $\partial p / \partial t$ eliminates the variable $t$and thus leaves us an ODE wrt $x$ for each step in $t$?

Comment: Hmm you wrote that you are looking for one ODE for each $\tau_{n}(t)$. Surely you meant an ODE in $t$? But yes an ODE in $x$ sounds more like what you'd want.

Comment: @Ali *But you wrote that you are looking for one ODE for each $\tau_n(t)$.* Hmmm now I'm not sure what I'm doing either. I was expecting something like $\tau_n'(t) = \text{(some constant)} \tau_n(t)$, so that I can solve for $\tau_n(t)$. Could you clarify on how can I find/approximate $\tau_n(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is the discretisation of time that I meant to suggest in the comments:
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{p(x,t)-p(x,t-\Delta t)}{\Delta t}
  = \left(12 x^{2} - 4\right) p(x,t)
  +\left(4 x \left(x^{2}- 1\right)+ 0.1\right)\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial x}
  +\frac{1}{\beta} \frac{\partial^{2} p(x,t)}{\partial x^{2}}.
\end{equation*}
That becomes
\begin{equation*}
  Ap=b
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
  A =
  1-\left(12 x^{2} - 4\right)\Delta t
  -\left(4 x \left(x^{2}- 1\right)+ 0.1\right)\Delta t\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
  -\frac{1}{\beta} \Delta t\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  b(x) = p(x,t-\Delta t).
\end{equation*}
In Python  the code might look something like

```
import numpy as np

T = 0.5
n = 10  # The number of time steps.
dt = T / n

N = 10  # The number of collocation points in the spatial dimension.
beta = whatever

# You need to work out the vector of collocation points x and differentiation matrix D.
# Look for the routine 'lobatto' in section 4.6.4 of Numerical Recipes and the routine
# 'weights' in section 20.7.8.

A = np.diag(1 - (12 * (x ** 2) - 4) * dt) -\
    (4 * x * (x ** 2 - 1) + 0.1) * dt * D - (1 / beta) * dt * D @ D
A = A[1:N-1, 1:N-1]  # That the boundary conditions are zero makes things simple.

def step(p):
    b = p[1:N-1]
    return np.hstack([0, np.linalg.solve(A, b), 0])

p = np.exp(-(x ** 2) / 2) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)

for i in range(n):
    p = step(p)
```

Edit: it seems the Chebyshev-Gauss-Lobatto points can be worked out more easily than by transcribing that routine from *Numerical Recipes*. [This page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) says :

> The Chebyshev–Gauss–Lobatto points are the zeros of $\left(1-x^{2}\right)T_{n}'(x)$. Using the property $T_{n}(x)=T_{n}(\cos\theta)=\cos(n\theta)$, these can be shown to be at $x_{j}=\cos(\pi j/n)$.

Edit 2: I was asked in the comments to make a plot ... here it is
[image]

produced by

```
T = 0.5
n = 20  # The number of time steps.
dt = T / n

N = 50  # The number of collocation points in the spatial dimension.
beta = 1

x = 3 * np.cos(np.linspace(-np.pi, 0, N))
w = [weights(xi, x, 2) for xi in x]
D = np.array([c[:, 1] for c in w]) / 3

A = np.eye(N) - D @ (np.diag(4 * x * (x ** 2 - 1) + 0.1)
    + (1 / beta) * D) * dt
A = A[1:N-1, 1:N-1]  # That the boundary conditions are zero makes things simple.

def step(p):
    b = p[1:N-1]
    return np.hstack([0, np.linalg.solve(A, b), 0])

p = np.exp(-(x ** 2) / 2) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)

for i in range(n):
    p = step(p)

grid = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
w = np.array([weights(gi, x, 0) for gi in grid]).reshape(100, N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(grid, w @ p)
```

Comment: Nice snippet - it would be great, if you may add a visualization. For Python there seems to exist a library called [pySpectralPDE](https://alanmatzumiya.github.io/pySpectralPDE/). Would this be helpful for the problem given here? Unfortunatelly I did not find out how to define the conditions there. And [this](https://github.com/spectralDNS/shenfun) sounds promising too.

Comment: @EldarSultanow I now have a plot.

Comment: That's stunning great!! Especially because you did every step by hand! I'will try it out now. Great done!

Comment: In order not to demand more from you (you have already done more than asked by OP), I would like to try creating a 3D variant. For this `grid = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)` and `w = np.array([weights(gi, x, 0) for gi in grid]).reshape(100, N)` can be extended - right? When I am aware of the data structure, I may create a [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/3d-surface-plots/) visualization for example. It is interactive and nice. I just need to understand how to obtain the 3D points.

Comment: I tried to add 3D capabilities to your script: https://www.kaggle.com/eldarsultanow/spectral/. Here is a first picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ7yB.png which emerges by just copying the values you generated along the y-axis. If you could help me a little bit, we can get it finalized. If you have a Kaggle user, I would be able to invite you for collaboration.

Comment: @EldarSultanow Thanks for your interest. I do have a Kaggle account that I have never used, 'alimew'. As for the help, I'm not entirely clear what you need, but maybe this goes some of the way?
```pp = np.empty((n + 1, 100))\\
p = np.exp(-(x ** 2) / 2) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)\\
pp[0] = w @ p\\
for i in range(n):\\p = step(p)\\pp[i + 1] = w @ p\\t = np.linspace(0, T, n + 1)\\xx, tt = np.meshgrid(grid, t)```

Comment: Thank you for your help - I added you (and still fighting to get it working). It would be great if you may check what is missing. I think we have to adjust these lines `w = np.array([weights(gi, x, 0) for gi in x_grid]).reshape(100, N)` and `z = [] for i in y_grid: z.append(w @ p)`. The loop over `y_grid` needs to be adjusted to curve the surface along $y$-direction.

Comment: @EldarSultanow I made some changes, can you see them? In fact my solution looks quite different to yours in the time direction, it seems to blow up.

Comment: If your solution blows up, then it's not stable. I'm not an expert of Python, but if I understand it correctly, you're using 2nd order difference formula for Chebyshev-Gauss-Lobatto grid? If so, this is not enough to handle the problem. You need to either use pseudospectral method to approximate the derivatives, or discretize in $x$ direction in a _cleverer_ way as discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/230431/1871).

Comment: @Ali: Yes I can see it - it works, it is progressing and looks amazing. Let us follow the hint of xzczd to make it looking completely similar. There seems to be a so-called conservation law to be considered. I tried to structure/generalize the code a bit by introducing variables and added contours to make the plot looking nicer, see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVFlC.png) :-). You can directly edit the [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/eldarsultanow/spectral/).

Comment: @xzczd I daresay you are right about some of that ... though not about the second order differences, my approach is already the pseudospectral one. I am comparing my plot to Eldar's [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4352426/427457), based on your post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/261835/using-ndsolvevalue-for-solving-a-parabolic-pde-numerically/261872#261872), and am confused by the apparent absence of any $(12 x^{2}-4)p$ term in the code?

Comment: It's there, if you expand $\partial_x((4 x (x^2 - 1) + 0.1) p)$ :)

Comment: Thanks. If I match that expression then I get a solution much like @EldarSultanow's. For some reason my original expression leads to a blow up—I've probably just made a silly mistake in the Python code.

Comment: I coud try out your update and generate this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tpxa.png, which looks amazing ($b=1$ on the left and $b=200$ on the right). Suggestion: put the updated code (including this picture) into your answer. We will also get the last little things fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I oriented myself to the approach described by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180453/solving-2d1-pde-with-pseudospectral-in-one-direction-with-periodic-boundary-con) entitled *"Solving 2D+1 PDE with Pseudospectral in one direction with periodic boundary condition?"* and used:

```
With[{p = p[x, t], mid = mid[x, t]},
 eq = D[p, t] == D[mid, x];
 eqadd = mid == (4 x (x^2 - 1) + 0.1) p + D[p/b, x];]
ic = p[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi];
icadd = mid[x, 0] == eqadd[[-1]] /. p -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate@ic[[-1]]];
bc = {p[-3, t] == 0, p[3, t] == 0};

mol[n:_Integer|{_Integer..}, o_:"Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

tst = NDSolveValue[{eq, eqadd, ic, icadd, bc}, p, {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0, 0.5}, 
    Method -> mol[300, 2]]; // AbsoluteTiming

Plot3D[tst[i, j], {i, -3, 3}, {j, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

I owe the key hints ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261838/84438), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261872/84438)) to make it running to the Mathematica community. As a result we obtain the following plots when choosing $b=1$ (left plot), $b=200$ (right plot):

[image]

We obtain the following two plots using `Plot[tst[i, 0.5], {i, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]` again for $b=1$ (left plot), $b=200$ (right plot):

[image]

***Update (2022-01-10):***

Fix according to [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261872/84438) including usage of "Pseudospectral" option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the zero boundary condition doesn't seem to hold: we should have $p(-3, t) = p(3, t) = 0$ for any $t$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I could fix it with the kind [help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261838/84438) of Mathematica Community. Hopefully the result makes sense now.

Comment: Additional experiment: A trial to deal with inconsistency of boundary and initial conditions by reformulating the initial conditions to `p[x, 0] == Which[0 < RealAbs[x] <= 3, Min[(3 - RealAbs[x])/.01, 1], True, 0] Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi]` leads to [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv1pD.png) plots.

Comment: As it stands, there's anything spectral about this. But I see in the first post you linked that there is an option "pseudospectral" you could try.

Comment: The option `Pseudospectral` (as part of [The Numerical Method of Lines](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html)) is now incorporated and the plots look nicer now.

Comment: Gosh well done! Mathematica can get pretty hairy can't it :) I see in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) it says: "'DifferenceOrder'->'Pseudospectral' use a pseudospectral derivative approximation; only applicable when the grid points are spaced corresponding to the Chebyshev–Gauss–Lobatto points or when the grid is uniform with PeriodicInterpolation->True". Does this case fall into one of those two categories?

Comment: I guess so - since if it wouldn't, then Mathematica yields errors and breaks the processing. But I totally agree - it would be great to have a Python-based implementation too. That's why I am really interested in trying out your solution, when extended by a visualization (using for example matplotlib, plotly, ...). There also exist frameworks implementing the Galerkin Spectral method - for example [spectralDNS](https://github.com/spectralDNS/shenfun). Can you imagine to produce these visualizations?

Comment: I tell you what, I'll revise my post if you can answer my question more definitively :)

Comment: The variable `A` is the grid containing the $(x,y)$-values- right? I am trying to figure out how to obtain the $z$-values. I am truely interested in getting your Python code understood, running and a visualization out of it (because I like Python very much).

Comment: The `A` in my post?

Comment: Yes - I am trying to comprehend it and would like to try incorporating a visualization into your snippet.

Comment: Well, actually `Pseudospectral` isn't used here, the difference order is `2` in this case. You can evaluate `mol[300, 2]` separately to see the actual option value. (The function `mol` is a helper function in my tool bag because these options are adjusted so frequently when playing with `NDSolve`. ) If one wants to choose `Pseudospectral`, try e.g. `mol[301]`, this also gives a good enough result.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clarification. A valid critique/question is: To what extent do we meet the requirement to have used the spectral method. Can this be justified?

Comment: Aha, the magic of `Pseudospectral` turns out to be effective for the problem, we don't even need to modify the form of the PDE! See my update in Mathematica.SE. "To what extent do we meet the requirement to have used the spectral method. Can this be justified?" If you're asking that, _can we make sure `NDSolve` has indeed used `Pseudospectral` method under the hood?_, then, the answer is yes. See the method here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204883/1871

Comment: A more advanced yet more plausible way to check that `Pseudospectral` method is chosen: `{state} = NDSolve\`ProcessEquations[{D[p[x, t], 
      t] == (12 x^2 - 4) p[x, t] + (4 x (x^2 - 1) + 0.1) D[p[x, t], x] + 
      D[p[x, t]/b, {x, 2}], p[x, 0] == Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 Pi], p[-3, t] == 0, 
    p[3, t] == 0}, p, {x, -3, 3}, {t, 0, 0.5}, Method -> mol[401]];
func = state["NumericalFunction"]["FunctionExpression"];
Cases[func, __NDSolve\`FiniteDifferenceDerivativeFunction, Infinity, Heads -> True][
  "DifferenceOrder"] // Through`

Comment: Great - I am just reading the update of your answer - it nicely simplifies the whole thing. (Next challenge will be to make a visualization running in Python :-) The approach of Ali looks very promising. Its all an interesting stuff!